# Camel Exchange on different routes in the same route builder

Tags: java, apache-camel

My REST application will post data to a queue (Q1) on rabbitMQ.  There's another separate application that will read from Q1, process the data and post the result back to Q2.  My application will read the data from Q2 and return the result.  Many clients will use these 2 queues so I generate a UUID and set it in the header so that I can listen on Q2 (the response topic).  I will then query each incoming message and match the incoming UUID in the header to the one I generated when I posted to Q1.

```
from("direct:test")
        .choice().when(isValid)
        .bean(FOOProcessor.class, "setFooQuery")
        .to(FOO_REQUEST_QUEUE).log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "body=${in.body}")
        .otherwise()
        .setBody(constant("error"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(400)).log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "body=${in.body}")
        .to("direct:error");
from(FOO_RESPONSE_QUEUE)
        .unmarshal(new JacksonDataFormat(JsonNode.class))
        .bean(FooProcessor.class, "setFooResponse")
        .to("direct:end");
from("direct:error").log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "end");
from("direct:end").log(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, "end");
```

The trouble is the 2 "from" statements - they create to separate Camel exchanges/contexts and I can't get the original UUID.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a processor that had a route builder embedded in it (with its own producer and consumer).
The processor provided a reference to the main exchange from this

```
process(final Exchange exchange)
```

Comment: could you please post the complete code snippet. I am looking for something like your usecase. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi. Too long ago, I'm afraid. I'm not sure what dodgy code I was writing but it looks like I passed the camel exchange through to processors who in turn called embedded routes. I'm not sure that that was the best way to go. Could you post a question in a separate thread and link it here?